# Design a free text box that includes image

Tags: html, css

I'm just starting with coding (HTML and CSS) and I have to create an opt-in form that has two free text boxes: one for name and one for email but they also have images in the right end of the free text box. (Unfortunately I cannot post an image.)

I can find my way around the free text boxes and the button but I am not sure how to include the images there.

Comment: Hi there. This isn't WriteMyCodeForMeOverflow, but if you post what you've tried to do -- both your HTML and CSS and maybe a [jsfiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.com) -- we'll be able to explain where you've gone wrong and point you in the right direction.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use CSS to set a background image in the textareas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this

**CSS**

```
#name{
    background:url(http://imagePath/ImageFile) no-repeat right;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="Name" id="name" />
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/oyupag/1/edit).

Answer (score 2):

sounds something like this:

```
input[type=text] {
    background: url(path/to/image) right 0 no-repeat;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TrqVU/) (on my demo I used a check-mark I found on Google images but you can use what you want/need.

Comment: Yes, that's actually what I was trying to achieve! Thank you!

Comment: One more question. I tried that and worked perfectly, but I'm also trying to add some margin to the right, but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: By 'margin to the right' what exactly do you mean? You can either have margin-right, which will push any elements to the right of the textbox a certain number of pixels to the right (http://cl.ly/JrsH - margin-right: 100px; - the orange colour represents margin) or padding-right, which will means you will not be able to type into a certain number of pixels on the right of the text box (http://cl.ly/JrxV - padding-right: 50px; - the green colour shows the padding). Good luck, i'm happy to answer any more questions :)